# Unable to connect Service with GoogleApi Client

Tags: java, android

I wanna make a Service Class which cannot be destroy and tells about the location using Google play Services after regular intervals 
Getting error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.gmaker.glocator.gps_trackers.Service_location@db35d39 with Intent { cmp=com.gmaker.glocator/.gps_trackers.Service_location }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
```

This is my Service class ondestroy it creates  Brodcastservice

```
public class Service_location extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = "Service_location";

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

     // Method to display the location
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Log.d(TAG, "Lat: "+latitude+"Long: "+longitude);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     * */
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        }
    }

    //Creating google api client object

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    //Creating location request object
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }


    // Method to verify google play services on the device

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported.");

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
     //Starting the location updates
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // First we need to check availability of play services
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            createLocationRequest();
        }
        // Show location button click listener

        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.gmaker.glocator");
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Broadcast Receiver

```
public class Reciever_location extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Service Stops", "Ohhhhhhh");
        context.startService(new Intent(context, Service_location.class));;
    }

}
```

In Manifest I have declared the service

```
<service android:name=".gps_trackers.Service_location" />
```

I have initialize my Service on main activity in function onCreate

Answer (score 0):

According to your error, you're approaching GoogleApiClient before `onConnected` is called.

You're calling `togglePeriodicLocationUpdates` from `onStartCommand` before the GoogleClientApi is connected.